# Zoom in on images in an Rmarkdown rendered to flex_dashboard

Tags: r, zooming, flexdashboard

I am adding images to an R markdown using `knitr::include_graphics` which is then rendered to a `flex_dashboard` (html output). The images are not very clear when added to the markdown and I was wondering if there was a way to add a zoom feature to them.

Here is my markdown template (test.Rmd):

````
---
title: Test Plot
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard: 
  fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

Test Plot
====================================

## Page 1

Row Page 7  {data-height=100}
-------------------------------------

### View1

```{r circos, fig.align='center', fig.width = 7, fig.height = 6}
knitr::include_graphics("data/tmpRCircos.png")
```
````

And here is the `tmpRCircos.png` file: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this something are you looking for ?

````
---
title: Zoom in on Plots
author: "MS"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard: 
  fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.zoomDiv {
  opacity: 0;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 50;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #888888;
  max-height:100%; 
  overflow: scroll;
}

.zoomImg {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').prepend("<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>");
    // onClick function for all plots (img's)
    $('img:not(.zoomImg)').click(function() {
      $('.zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '1', width: '60%'});
    });
    // onClick function for zoomImg
    $('img.zoomImg').click(function() {
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '0', width: '0%'});
    });
  });
</script>

## First Slide


```{r circos, fig.align='center', fig.width = 2, fig.height = 1}
knitr::include_graphics("./tmpRCircos.png")
```
````