# Rmarkdown cannot render `DT::datatable` and lose "table of contents" functionality when html/php code added

Tags: javascript, php, html, r, r-markdown

I am generating an rmarkdown report, in html format, with some figures and tables; some tables can have a column of figures and a column of characters/numbers. Also, some figures are locally stored, some figures are instantly generated.

I want "click&zoom" functionality for all the figures in the html report. I found this solution [Zoom in on images in an Rmarkdown rendered to flex_dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313317/zoom-in-on-images-in-an-rmarkdown-rendered-to-flex-dashboard) and it works nicely. However, once I add the linked html chunk in my rmarkdown.Rmd file, I no longer have the typical rmarkdown table of contents on the top-left corner, and `DT::datatable` can no longer render the table in the final html report.

What can I do to have click&zoom functionality for all the figures in rmarkdown html report and not lose mentioned functionalities?

Edit: I tried using `options = list(dom="Bt")` as referenced here [DT::datatable won't render results in HTML R markdown report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884674/dtdatatable-wont-render-results-in-html-r-markdown-report) , and it did not help.

Comment: I found my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59401761/6870414

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zoom function in rmarkdown html plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361986/zoom-function-in-rmarkdown-html-plot)